# Tweepy Streaming - Stop collecting tweets at x amount

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm looking to have the Tweepy Streaming API stop pulling in tweets after I have stored x # of tweets in MongoDB.

I have tried IF and WHILE statements inside the class, defintion with counters, but cannot get it to stop at a certain X amount. This is a real head-banger for me. I found this link here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tweepy/5IGlu2Qiug4   but my efforts to replicate this have failed. It always tells me that **init** needs an additional argument. I believe we have our Tweepy auth set different, so it is not apples to apples.

Any thoughts?

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json, time, sys

import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        text = status.text
        created = status.created_at
        record = {'Text': text, 'Created At': created}
        print record #See Tweepy documentation to learn how to access other fields
        collection.insert(record)  


    def on_error(self, status):
        print 'Error on status', status

    def on_limit(self, status):
        print 'Limit threshold exceeded', status

    def on_timeout(self, status):
        print 'Stream disconnected; continuing...'


stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())
stream.filter(track=['tv'])
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a counter inside of your class in `__init__`, and then increment it inside of `on_status`. Then when the counter is below 20 it will insert a record into the collection. This could be done as show below:

```
def __init__(self, api=None):
    super(StdOutListener, self).__init__()
    self.num_tweets = 0

def on_status(self, status):
    record = {'Text': status.text, 'Created At': status.created_at}
    print record #See Tweepy documentation to learn how to access other fields
    self.num_tweets += 1
    if self.num_tweets < 20:
        collection.insert(record)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Adding the __init__ gives me this error: "'StdOutListener' object has no attribute 'api'"  http://i.imgur.com/Z2N3hCB.png   I am not sure what adding that has to do with the api?

Comment: Sorry about that, you also need to add a call to the init of the base class. I updated the code about, but it is as simple as adding a line `super(StdOutListener, self).__init__()` to the definition of init.

Comment: To reduce errors in future, I'd better conform `__init__` definition with StreamListener's one: `def __init__(self, api=None):`, and call it whith api param.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! So for my understanding, why did this need a call back to the base class init? When I don't call it, but added api=None, it gives the "no attribute api" error. Is the purpose of the super init to call back to the base class that DOES have an api attribute?

Comment: In tweepy I get this error `NameError: global name 'StdOutListener' is not defined` how should I use count in init?

Comment: That line is just trying to call super on the class you're initializing. You can change `StdOutListener` to whatever you're calling your `StreamListener` subclass. eg. the code from my response should go inside the `StdOutListener` class.

Comment: @AngryWhopper I've been dealing with this error for a few hours now and wouldn't have thought the `__init()__` method would have caused it! +1 for catching that