# What is the best way to have a method to stop tweepy stream?

Tags: python, object, twitter, tweepy

Whenever I create a status stream object I start streaming information from the twitter API. If I want to do a method to stop the stream what would be the way of doing so? The method I need some help with is stopStream() which would stop the twitter stream whenever that method is called.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    from tweepy import Stream
    import time
    import json
    import csv
    import sys
    import Tweet
    import DatabaseInteractor 
    import twitter_credentials




class StatusStream(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):

      self.continueStream = True
      super(StatusStream, self).__init__()


      def on_status(self, status):

          print(status.text)
          if(self.continueStream ==False):
            return False 





    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return False

    @staticmethod
    def stopStream():
      self.continueStream = False


auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_credentials.API_KEY,twitter_credentials.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN,twitter_credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitterStream = Stream(auth=auth, listener=StatusStream(),tweet_mode='extended')
twitterStream.filter(track=["plumber","visa","bathtub"])
```

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498975/unable-to-stop-streaming-in-tweepy-after-one-minute